# python how to read a tsv file, clean it and save as new file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to remove all punctuations from column 4 of my tsv file and then save the entire file. This is my code:

```
import csv
import string

exclude = set(string.punctuation)

with open("test1") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        line[4] = ''.join(ch for ch in line[4] if ch not in exclude)
    tsvfile.close()
```

The code above works fine, but my file did not save with the changes i made. How can i save the changes within the old file?

Comment: Changing `line` doesn't change a file unless you actually write it to a file.

Comment: You need to create a new file that has your changes in it. For an example of doing that see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166265/355230).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not writing any changes, you are simply changing each fifth element in each row and doing nothing with it, if you want to change the original file you can write to a `tempfile` and do a `shutil.move` to replace the original file with the updated temp:

```
import string

exclude = string.punctuation
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("test1") as tsvfile, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as t:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    temp = csv.writer(t,delimiter="\t")
    for row in tsvreader:
        row[4] = row[4].strip(exclude)
        temp.writerow(row)

move(t.name,"test1")
```

If you want to create a new file instead of updating the original you just need to open a new file and write each cleaned row:

```
with open("test1") as tsvfile, open("out","w") as  t:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    temp = csv.writer(t,delimiter="\t")
    for row in tsvreader:
        row[4] = row[4].strip(exclude)
        temp.writerow(row)
```

To strip punctuation `str.strip(exclude)` will be sufficient. If you want to remove from anywhere you can go back to `''.join([ch for ch in line[4] if ch not in exclude])` but if you were removing from anywhere then you should use `str.translate`:

```
 row[4] = row[4].translate(None,exclude)
```

If you want to add a space:

```
from string import maketrans
tbl = maketrans(exclude," "*len(exclude))

....
row[4] = row[4].translate(tbl)
```

Lastly if you actually mean the fourth column then it would be `row[3]` not `row[4]`

Comment: `strip(exclude) != ''.join(ch for ch in line[4] if ch not in exclude)`, but you've now pointed that out and fixed it, so downvote removed. Good point about the column number... net result: downvote converted to an upvote.

Comment: @mhawke, based on the OP expecting the file to have been changed by changing the element in the list I took an educated guess that strip might be what they  actually want, translating or using the join approach  will change `foo's` to `foos` which may or may not be what the OP actually wants.

Comment: I don't see how the two are related, although I think you are probably right that the OP wants to update the file inplace.

Comment: hi i got this error:     `row[4] = row[4].strip(exclude)
TypeError: strip arg must be None, str or unicode`. Also, there is a typo in your second `delimiter`

Comment: @jxn,  do you have `exclude = string.punctuation` in your code?

Comment: what does `print(type(exclude))` output?

Comment: it gives `<type 'set'>`.. oh maybe its the set

Comment: how can i replace punctuation with white space instead?

Comment: yes, i realized my words are sticking together where commas used to be in place

Comment: Do you actually want to remove from anywhere or just strip from the ends?

Comment: yea i want to remove all punctuations cos i need to convert my file to csv after

Answer (score 2):

You say that you want a new file, so you will need to open a second file and write the cleaned rows to it:

```
import csv
import string

exclude = string.punctuation

with open("test1") as tsvfile, open('out.csv') as outfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    tsvwriter = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in tsvreader:
        row[4] = row[4].translate(None, string.punctuation)
        tsvwriter.writerow(row)
```

This uses `str.translate()` to remove all unwanted punctuation characters from the column. The above is for Python 2. For Python 3 use this:

```
row[4] = row[4].translate({ord(c): None for c in string.punctuation})
```

Comment: It is quite different to your initial answer. Your edits came through while I added my answer. Seems to happen a lot with you :)

Comment: I would be almost willing to bet that the initial answer is actually what the OP wants, they were hoping the code they used would change the original file so the shutil approach is the way to go  if that is the case.